# put values of mysql_fetch_array in a String separated by ;

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make a web service and I want to return only one row and set the values ​​of the row in a chain like: value1; value2; value2; ie separated; each column of the row

I have written this code:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM base WHERE id =" $id;
  $result = mysql_query ($query, $link);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
```

but I do not now how to put a string value of each row separated by;

Can anyone help? thank you

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Why do you add a space after every `$` ? and missing a trailing `;`, and there is an extra `.` at line 1. Have you ever debug yourself?

Comment: Raptor sorry I translated with google translate the post and he has added spaces

Comment: Function called `implode` may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach loop.

```
$values = '';
foreach ( $row as $value ){
    if ( $value == end($row) )
        $values .= $value
    else
        $values .= $values .';';
}
```